# Javascript Export/Print to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to export / print a div to PDF, however the "div" format in the PDF is not what I really want. I'm having two problems:

**1st Problem:**

When I click the print button, it opens a page already with the pdf, but the first line, it fills everything. See picture to see what I mean.

[image]

**2nd problem**

In the div I have included ACTIONS ... I want you to do the export / print ... this "section is deleted and does not appear because it is not necessary. See image to see what I want.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<table id="table_id" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID_Cliente
            </th>
            <th>
                Nome
            </th>
            <th>
                Morada
            </th>
            <th>
                Telemóvel
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Ações
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Cliente)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
                </td>
                @if (User.IsInRole("Administrador"))
                {
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Morada)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telemovel)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>
                }
                else
                {
                <td>
                    xxxxxxx
                </td>
                <td>
                    xxxxxxx
                </td>
                <td>
                    xxxxxxx
                </td>
                }
                <td class="buttons">
                    <div class="buttons" role="group" aria-label="Botões">
                        <a href='@Url.Action("Edit","Clientes",new { id=item.ID_Cliente }, Request.Url.Scheme)' class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</a>
                        <a href='@Url.Action("Details","Clientes", new { id=item.ID_Cliente }, Request.Url.Scheme)' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Detalhes</a>
                        <a href='@Url.Action("Delete","Clientes", new { id=item.ID_Cliente }, Request.Url.Scheme)' class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Eliminar</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnPrint").on("click", function () {
            var divContents = $("#table_id").html();
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Lista de Clientes</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stripping the "`<table>`" tag from the table element, that should be around the divContents variable for the table to display correctly.

For the last columns, you can simply hide them before getting the divContents variable and display them afterwards. If you are up for it you can also clone the table element and remove the last column, and use the html() on the cloned element.

For simply hiding/showing the last column your code would be:

```
    $("#btnPrint").on("click", function () {
        $("#table_id th:last-child, #table_id td:last-child").hide();
        var divContents = $("#table_id").html();
        $("#table_id th:last-child, #table_id td:last-child").show();
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Lista de Clientes</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write('<table>' + divContents + '</table>');
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
    });
```